# Autocomplete difficulties on jQuery and typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been experimenting with the [Typeahead](http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/) JavaScript plugin and trying to integrate it into my current form in order to exploit its possibilities. So far I have managed to accomplish the following:

```
<span class="typeahead-query">
     <input type="text" class="form-control booking" 
      id="pickup" placeholder="From" name="country_v1[query]">
</span>
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7pha0Ltb/)

However this does not produce anything. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Furthermore, I wanted to ask if Typeahead is now considered to be better than something like jQuery UI autocomplete.

Comment: You're missing the wrapper containers as shown in the demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `span` into 2 elements with class `typeahead-container` and `typeahead-field`, e.g. :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Typeahead
  $('#pickup').typeahead({
    order: "desc",
    source: {
      data: [
        "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda",
        "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh",
        "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
        "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma",
        "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad",
        "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the",
        "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti",
        "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador",
        "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon",
        "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea",
        "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India",
        "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan",
        "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
        "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
        "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
        "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Monaco",
        "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",
        "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
        "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino",
        "Sao Tome", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone",
        "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain",
        "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan",
        "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
        "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States",
        "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
      ]
    },
    callback: {
      onInit: function(node) {
        console.log('Typeahead Initiated on ' + node.selector);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.runningcoder.org/vendor/runningcoder/jquery-typeahead/jquery.typeahead.js"></script>

<div class="typeahead-container">
  <div class="typeahead-field">
    <span class="typeahead-query">
        <input type="text" class="form-control booking" id="pickup" placeholder="From" name="country_v1[query]"/>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you are interested in another solution for autocomplete, take a look at [Twitter Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) (it's my favorite so far).